# Error class not Found fixed but I don't understand why

Tags: java, cloud9-ide, cloud9

The file "HelloDemo.java" path is "/test/hello/HelloDemo.java"

```
package test.hello;

public class HelloDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.print("Hello!!");
  }
}
```

when I "run" it, an error occurred.

```
Building HelloDemo.java and running HelloDemo
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloDemo
```

Then, I changed the code.

```
//package test.hello;

public class HelloDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.print("Hello!!");
  }
}
```

when I "Run" it, code success output.

```
Building HelloDemo.java and running HelloDemo
Hello!!
```

This is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkbo9.png) about the "Run".
I fixed an error, but I don't konw why, I need help, Thank you!

**If I want to keep the package uncomment, How to fix it?**

Comment: Your first "unfixed" version runs just as fine as the second one. Did you maybe forget to save it after adding the main method?

Comment: I've saved it before it runs. My IDE is ide.cloud9.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you probably changed the location of your file after running it once already. Hence, the running configuration should change to look for the new test.hello.HelloDemo class inside the built jar and not for HelloDemo anymore (which was probably in the default package, initially). What is your IDE?

**Remark**: This is not because you changed the location of your file that the classpath changed, and vice-versa.

On IntelliJ, you should do this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Comment: My IDE is ide.cloud9.io

Comment: Check this link: https://docs.c9.io/docs/running-and-debugging-code And modify the running configuration to set the correct class. If you put "package X.Y" inside the file, then your classpath is X.Y.ClassName

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if as this answers your question.

Comment: If I want to keep the package uncomment, How to fix it?

Comment: If you want to keep the package X.Y; statement, you need two things: 1 - create the package hierarchy (X/Y/MyClass) and 2 - update your running configuration on your IDE to launch the given X.Y.MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

Create a package using your IDE and add your class to it. Package name will be appended to top automatically.
Reguardless of IDE, folder structure should match package structure, your problem could be here.

Comment: Package name will be appended to top automatically in the cloud9 IDE? Why I can't see it?

Comment: You'll have to match folder hierarchy to package hierarchy manually then.

Answer (score 0):

A class's name is actually the package plus the class name. You cannot run `HelloDemo` in your first case, because that is not the class name. The class name is `test.hello.HelloDemo`.

By commenting out the package, you've essentially renamed the class to `HelloDemo`, so it runs.

In addition, when running the class with main, you must be in the correct location. For instance, if the class is `test.hello.HelloDemo`, your folder structure will be `/test/hello/HelloDemo.java`.

You must be in `/` and run `test.hello.HelloDemo` from there.